# How to enable the root element in tree view

Tags: kendo-ui

I am working on kendo tree view. Its working well in Google Chrome. When testing that the root node is not in a selected state in IE and firefox. Can any one tell what were the reasons that may occur.

```
  <div id="treeview"></div>


var data = [
        {
            id   : 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder",
            items: [
                                { id: 2, text: "w" },
                                { id: 3, text: "wq" },
                                { id: 4, text: "q" },
                                { id: 5, text: "qq" },
                                { id: 6, text: "qeq" },
                                { id: 7, text: "gd" }
                            ]

               }
    ];

var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    dataSource: data
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Comment: How about a code sample?

Comment: With the above  client code it was running properly.But the problem is while getting data from server side the parent event was not rising until the child element has selected

Comment: please suggest me instead of using $("#treeview").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", true); any other function that enable all the checked item default in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the problem for last comment:

*please suggest me instead of using $("#treeview").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", true); any other function that enable all the checked item default in all browsers*

Add [change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#events-change) event and change whatever you want in [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

```
$("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item").each(function(){
    // change whatever you want, for example:
    $(this).css("color","green");
});
```

This is similar to what you're using, but I've checked it in Chrome, Firefox and IE and works fine. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCZU4/4/) (adapted from KendoUI demos).

Comment: How to make the tree parent node as checked by default

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KCZU4/1/   the parent node should be cheecked state by deffault.Its not woring in forefox

Comment: How to make the tree parent node as checked by default.Beacuse the same problem is getting with above js fiddle in firefox.

Comment: See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrTrJ/). It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE as previous did. If you're using external datasource you could add change event into datasource initialization so it's a bit cleaner code.